# In vscode 'go to definition' doesn't work with import modules in .js files when alias is used

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules, go-to-definition

I have vue project.
Go to definition works fine in .vue files, either I use alias or not.

But in .js files 'go to definition' works only if I don't use alias (checked with the same module).

It strange for me since jsconfig.json is the same.

````
  "include": ["designs/*", "mocks/*", "base/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@resh/*": ["./designs/resh/*"],
      "@academia/*": ["./designs/academia/*"],
      "packages/*": ["./packages/*"]
    }
  }
}```
````